# Image stacking and averaging tool for Windows

Tags: windows, photography, image-editing, photoshop

In Lightroom/Photoshop I can easily create many layers of photos to create "virtual long exposures" and reduce noise through image averaging. However RawTherapee and Darktable just don't appear to have support for that and I don't want to use Adobe software anymore.
I'm looking for a good tool for Windows 10 to do that. It can be a full editor or a specific tool for that purpose. I want it to be free or much more affordable than Adobe's suite. Optionally, I would prefer open source tools that also work on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) as well as the panorama stitching that everybody knows it for can do:

- Exposure Correction,
- White Balance Correction,
- Exposure stacking  **with alignment** *so you don't have to have used a tripod*
- Focal Stacking **also with alignment**
- Barrel Distortion
- HDR

The stitcher options page from the expert interface gives some clues:
[image: Expert Stitcher Options]

It is free, gratis & Open Source, and cross platform.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it could do it. I'll have a look at it